# There is no output when i try to scrape off this page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im using a discord bot for a small community and im trying to display the number of online players on a specific game. The code im using here to me looks ok, but this is my first time scraping, so i may be asking for it to look for the wrong keywords. The module loads fine with no errors, but when entering the trigger to display the information, nothing happens. can anyone point out to me wheat i may have missed or input wrong myself

Here is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
try: # check if BeautifulSoup4 is installed
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soupAvailable = True
except:
    soupAvailable = False
import aiohttp

class bf1online:
    """My custom cog that does stuff!"""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        """This does stuff!"""

        #Your code will go here
@commands.command()
async def bf1(self):
    """How many players are online atm?"""

    #Your code will go here
    url = "http://bf1stats.com/" #build the web adress
    async with aiohttp.get(url) as response:
        soupObject = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "html.parser") 
    try:
        online = soupObject.find(id_='online_section').find('h2').find('p').find('b').get_text()
        await self.bot.say(online + ' players are playing this game at the moment')
    except:
        await self.bot.say("Couldn't load amount of players. No one is playing this game anymore or there's an error.")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(bf1online(bot))
```

Comment: Please copy & paste your code into your question as text instead of posting an image.

Comment: done, although its broke it up some.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is it should be `id=` not `id_=`, no trailing underscore.

```
 soupObject.find(id='online_section')
```

The next problem is that looks like:

```
<div id="online_section">
        Loading currently playing player counts...

</div>
```

Because that is rendered using Js. Luckily you can mimic the ajax call that gets the data quite easily:

```
In [1]: import requests
...: data = 
requests.get("http://api.bf1stats.com/api/onlinePlayers").json()
   ...: 

In [2]: data
Out[2]: 
{'pc': {'count': 126870, 'label': 'PC', 'peak24': 179935},
 'ps4': {'count': 237504, 'label': 'PS4', 'peak24': 358182},
 'xone': {'count': 98474, 'label': 'XBOXONE', 'peak24': 266869}}
```